# C++ covariant return type error with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, c++98, covariant

I have the code which is equivalent to this one:

```
class X {};
class Y {};

template< typename T>
  class C {
  public:
      virtual  T * foo() = 0;
  };

class A : public C< X> {
public:
    X * foo() {};
};

class B : public A {};

class D : public B, public C< Y> {
public:
    Y * foo() {}; //this is the only one method I need here. Not A::foo!
};
```

I got this errors:

```
error:   invalid covariant return type for 'virtual Y* D::foo()'
 Y * foo() {};
     ^
```

and:

```
error:   overriding 'virtual X* A::foo()'
 X * foo() {};
     ^
```

http://ideone.com/PAgTdX

I believe I could write something in *class B* or *D* to prevent *A::foo* from inheriting, but I don't know what. Maybe there is some feature to rename conflict names in C++?

PS> I can't use C++11, only good old C++98.

Comment: If the `foo` inherited from `C<Y>` is the only one you want, then why are you inheriting from `B`? This seems like a symptom of an underlying design problem.

Comment: B and D are two classes which I use in my code separately.

Comment: I have asked a question that's similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240936/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-ast-using-visitor-pattern-with-return-value, the 2nd answer may provide what you want, but it does need c++11.

Comment: Where do you see covariance being used in this example? Covariance would imply that an overriding method returns a subtype of the return type of the overridden method, which is not the case here?

Comment: You right, covariance here is only because of the error "invalid covariant return type".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***TL;DR***

Overriding `foo` in class `D`. `foo` methods can not covariant due to unrelated `X` and `Y` return types. Neither, can not overload due to different return types but same signature.

---

***Explanation***

Let's clean up the code to a smaller snippet with same issue:

```
class X {};
class Y {};

template<typename T>
class C {
public:
    virtual T * foo() = 0;
};

class A : public C<X> {
public:
    // Your code:
    // X * foo() {}; <---- This method is irrelevant to the problem

    // virtual X * foo() {};
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // This method declared via inheritance and template
    // and implicitly exists in this class, (look at keyword `virtual`)
};

class D : public A, public C<Y> {
public:
    /*virtual*/ Y * foo() {}; // `virtual` comes from C<X>
};
```

Well, class `D` inherits two `foo` methods from `A` and `C<Y>`. These two imported methods can co-exists because they come from different parents and they can be called by qualified calls, for example `D d; d.A::foo();`.

But in this situation, the problem comes into the picture, when you try to override `foo` in class `D`:

```
/*virtual*/ Y * foo() {};
```

In class `D`, there is a method with signature `X * foo()` inherited from `A` and you're overriding method `Y * foo()`. These can not covariant, [because `Y` is not derived from `X`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4665163/952747). On the other hand, this `foo` can not overload another one, [Because return type is not part of function signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type).

It's good to read the error message of clang:

> error: return type of virtual function 'foo' is not covariant with the
>   return type of the function it overrides ('Y *' is not derived from 'X
>   *')
>
> ```
> virtual Y * foo() {};
> ```

---

***Solution***

The best solution is to simplify your design and get rid of these complex inheritance, templated and same name methods!!

Comment: Thank you for clear and full answer. A code which you are giving (without implementation of _foo_ method in _A_ class) will not compile even if there is no inheritance of _D_ class. If I understand you right.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you don't need the `foo` method you declare in `C<X>` and implement in `A`, but since your class `D` also is-an `A` and a `C<X>`, clients might depend on this method being available, and returning an `X`. C++ doesn't support removing inherited methods AFAIK, and for good reason, as this would violate the Liskov substitution principle.

If you did remove or hide `C<X>::foo` here, then an instance of `D` could not be used where an instance of `A`, `B`, or `C<X>` is expected. So I'm afraid that there is no good solution for this problem here. If you are only trying to reuse implementation from `A` or `B` in `D`, then maybe you should consider composition instead of inheritance in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [private inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance) for A.

```
class B : private A {};
```

In general, the return type cannot be the only difference for overloading.